# High Page Faults/sec low Page Reads/sec

Tags: sql-server, memory, performance, performance-tuning

I currently have Page Faults/sec avergaing 1269 while my Page Reads/sec is averaging 0.3.

I am just trying to interpret what this means.  I assume I am getting lots of soft page faults in this case and the issue the user is experiencing with slowness is due to the application having to wait on pages to become free in memory?

In which case should I be tracking locking and blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting soft faults and this is a non-issue. Soft faults are part of the normal page lifetime as the [process working set gets continuously trimmed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441804(VS.85).aspx).

If you also experience application problems then you need to investigate the cause. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) for a starting point.

Comment: Thats a great link thanks.  What do you think to tracking locks and blocks would this be the next logical step in troubleshooting the poor performance?

Comment: Concurrency and performance are closely related.  Blocking is often due to queries touching more data than needed for the task and performance is generally improved by touching the minimal amount of data.  I suggest you first follow the Identifying Problem Queries section of the article.  Ensure existing indexes are used as expected and predicates are sargable.